# Scrapy Playwright: execute CrawlSpider using scrapy playwright

Tags: scrapy, playwright, playwright-python

Is it possible to execute CrawlSpider using Playwright integration for Scrapy? I am trying the following script to execute a CrawlSpider but it does not scrape anything. It also does not show any error!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class GumtreeCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'gumtree_crawl'
    allowed_domains = ['www.gumtree.com']
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.gumtree.com/property-for-sale/london/page',
            meta={"playwright": True}
        )
        return super().start_requests()

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='grid-col-12']/ul[1]/li/article/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
    )

    async def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'Title': response.xpath("//div[@class='css-w50tn5 e1pt9h6u11']/h1/text()").get(),
            'Price': response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='price']/text()").get(),
            'Add Posted': response.xpath("//dl[@class='css-16xsajr elf7h8q4'][1]/dd/text()").get(),
            'Links': response.url
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests extracted from the rule do not have the `playwright=True` meta key, that's a problem if they need to be rendered by the browser to have useful content. You could solve that by using [`Rule.process_request`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule), something like:

```py
def set_playwright_true(request, response):
    request.meta["playwright"] = True
    return request

class MyCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    ...
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(...), callback='parse_item', follow=False, process_request=set_playwright_true),
    )
```

**Update after [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71459599/scrapy-playwright-execute-crawlspider-using-scrapy-playwright/71462253?noredirect=1#comment126324451_71462253)**

1. Make sure your URL is correct, I get no results for that particular one (remove `/page`?).
2. Bring back your `start_requests` method, seems like the first page also needs to be downloaded using the browser
3. Unless marked explicitly (e.g. `@classmethod`, `@staticmethod`) Python instance methods receive the calling object as implicit first argument. The convention is to call this `self` (e.g. `def set_playwright_true(self, request, response)`). However, if you do this, you will need to change the way you create the rule, either:

   - `Rule(..., process_request=self.set_playwright_true)`
   - `Rule(..., process_request="set_playwright_true")`

   From [the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule): "process_request is a callable (or a string, in which case a method from the spider object with that name will be used)"

   My original example defines the processing function outside of the spider, so it's not an instance method.

Comment: as you suggested, I tried something like this. But failed to execute

https://pastebin.com/raw/pyYzwa6v

Comment: Updated the answer in response to the above comment

Comment: If I only need the html page dynamically loaded by the chromium browser it works perfect.
I need to interact with the page, clicking  buttons, waiting, to then take the final html.
I tried to mix your solution with the one from documentation which passes the page to the parse method by adding to the meta dict playwright_include_page = True and them taking it from response object   page = response.meta["playwright_page"].
No error but the "playwright_page" is not defined.
link-> 
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright#:~:text=produces%20the%20same,.close()

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by elacuesta, I'd only add change your "parse_item" def from an async to a standard def.

> def parse_item(self, response):

It defies what all I've read too, but that got me through.